# Unhiding a panel client side / hiding it server side?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to unhide a panel client side by setting it's style.  I initial setting for the style property is: display: none;

I am tying to unhide it with the following code:

```
 var fileUploadPanel = dojo.byId("fileUploadPanel");
 var fileUpload1 = dojo.byId("fileUpload1");
 dojo.style(fileUploadPanel, "display", "block");
 fileUpload1.focus();
```

But I get a javscript error style is null or not an object.  Any idea why?  the panel should have a style property correct?

Also as a follow up, I need to be able to hide that panel again with another button but it has to be SSJS.  Anyway to do this?

Comment: To your follow up question: What are you trying to do? Why has it to be SSJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use the client id instead?

```
 dojo.byId("#{id:fileUploadPanel}");
 var fileUpload1 = dojo.byId("#{id:fileUpload1}");
```

Comment: Thanks Sven.  This one keeps biting me.  I guess I was assuming that the byId function would convert it for me.   Locked into my memory now. :)